# Is it mandatory to use "addFlags" in order to launch other app's component explicitly?

Tags: android, android-intent, explicit-intent

Using my Android app, I'm trying to launch an external app's component explicitly.

```
ComponentName name =  new ComponentName("other.app.android", "other.app.android.Activity1");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8111");
Intent abc = new Intent();
abc.setData(uri);
abc.setComponent(name);
startActivity(abc);
```

Should I add these two lines in order to make it run correctly?

(1) `abc.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");`

(2) `abc.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I add these two lines in order to make it run correctly?

"run correctly" is a matter of interpretation. You need to decide what you want to have!

> (1) abc.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

This is not necessary. the DEFAULT category is added automatically to the implicit search criteria when you call `startActivity()`.

> (2) abc.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

You can add this if you want the target `Activity` to be started in a new task (ie: not in the existing task). If you dson't add this flag, the target `Activity` will be started in the current task. It depends on the behaviour that you want to have.